# Django Model object creation method

Tags: django, django-models

I'm having two models where `UserGroup` model, which contains a group admin, and `DetailedUser` model which related to the group model, where the field `user` points all users in the certain `UserGroup`, I want to add a field that when a new user added to the group it store its date and time of user added to the particular group.

```
class UserGroup(models.Model):
    group_admin = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='group_by')
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    group_amount = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.group_name

class DetailedUser(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(UserGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_group')
    user = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, related_name='single_user')
    user_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.group.group_name}"
```

How can I done this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your model design is not correct. What you need(I think) is [ManyToManyField with `though`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through). For example:

```
class UserGroup(models.Model):
    group_admin = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='group_by')
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    group_amount = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="DetailedUser")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.group_name

class DetailedUser(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(UserGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_group')
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name='single_user')
    user_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.group.group_name}"
```

Usage example:

```
>> group = UserGroup.objects.get(pk=1)
>> user = User.objects.first()
>> DetailedUser.objects.create(group=group, user=user)
>> group.memebers.all()
```